# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'N' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm pulling my hair with this one. Follow closely, please.

When I run this, I get 27 rows returned:

```
select * 
from dbo.[12STD_NO_VISIT] 
where (
         (dbo.fPhoneExists(PhoneNumber1) = 1  
         AND (NextCall1 BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(hh, 1, GETDATE())))
      )
```

And when I run this, I get 21 rows returned (notice the change to PhoneNumber2 and NextCall2):

```
select * 
from dbo.[12STD_NO_VISIT] 
where (
          (dbo.fPhoneExists(PhoneNumber2) = 1  
           AND (NextCall2 BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(hh, 1, GETDATE())))
      )
```

But, when I run this, 'ORing' the 2 conditions, I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'N' to data type int

```
select * 
from dbo.[12STD_NO_VISIT] 
where (
          (dbo.fPhoneExists(PhoneNumber1) = 1  
           AND (NextCall1 BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(hh, 1, GETDATE())))
       OR  
          (dbo.fPhoneExists(PhoneNumber2) = 1
           AND (NextCall2 BETWEEN GETDATE() AND  DATEADD(hh, 1, GETDATE())))
      )
```

But it doesn't just give me the error. It first retrieves 42 rows, displaying that for a split second (Results tab), and then it displays the error (Messages tab).

I can't figure this one out. Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks!

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[fPhoneExists](@PhoneNumber varchar) 
RETURNS BIT 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @GoodNumber bit 
IF (@PhoneNumber is NULL or @PhoneNumber = 0 or @PhoneNumber = '') 
  SET @GoodNumber = 0; 
ELSE 
  SET @GoodNumber = 1; 
  Return(@GoodNumber); 
END
```

Comment: What happens if you try to `UNION` both queries?

Comment: What does the `fPhoneExists` function like look like?

Comment: Hah. I get it now. 42. Answer to everything indeed.

Comment: @Lynn Crumbling +1 to comment for allusion to Hitchhiker's Guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are the data types of `PhoneNumber1` and `PhoneNumber2`? What is the definition of `dbo.fPhoneExists`? I suspect the problem lies there somewhere - or as Lynn suggests maybe there is more to the query than you've shown us (the query would either succeed or fail as a whole; it wouldn't produce 42 rows and then an error).

Now that we see the function, here is a re-write:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fPhoneExists]
(
  @PhoneNumber VARCHAR -- varchar(what)? This should match definition of column
) 
RETURNS BIT 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER 
AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(@PhoneNumber, '') IN ('0', '') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
END
GO
```

There is no reason to store the temporary logic in a variable, also notice that you are returning the variable *only* in the ELSE condition.

Comment: Hi Aaron, here's the code for the function: 'FUNCTION [dbo].[fPhoneExists](PhoneNumber varchar)
RETURNS BIT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE GoodNumber bit
 IF (PhoneNumber is NULL or PhoneNumber = 0 or PhoneNumber = '') 
  SET GoodNumber = 0;
 ELSE
  SET GoodNumber = 1;
Return(GoodNumber);
END; Before the variables goes a '@', only that it didn't let me post it here. I also don't know how to format in this posts for readability. Sorry.

Comment: Please add the function to the question and format it as a code sample. It's very hard to read as a plain text comment (also all the @ signs are stripped). If you edit the question you can highlight the code and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Also, in your simplified code I don't see NEXTCALL2. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Amarundo - Change this part of your function: `or PhoneNumber = 0` to `or PhoneNumber = '0'`

Comment: @Amarundo - Glad it helped you. I recommend that you post that solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Amarundo  Also declare a width for your `varchar` params

Comment: @AaronBertrand - You are right. I just couldn't find a way to format that code and didn't know how to edit the original question. Will do next time!

Answer (score 3):

Your `dbo.fPhoneExists` function contains an implicit cast in the `PhoneNumber = 0` expression that, according to the rules of [Data Type Peecendence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) casts the `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR value to an int. This cast will fail if the value in the string is not a numeric. You are also falling into the fallacy of assuming that boolean operator short circuit is guaranteed in SQL, which is simply not true. SQL is a declarative language and the [order of evaluation of boolean operators is **not guaranteed**](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll get better performance replacing `fnPhoneExists` by replacing the function with a `CASE`:

```
select * 
from dbo.[12STD_NO_VISIT] 
where (
          (case when ISNULL(PhoneNumber1,'') not in ('0','') then 1 else 0 end=1
           AND (NextCall1 BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(hh, 1, GETDATE())))
       OR  
          (case when ISNULL(PhoneNumber2,'') not in ('0','') then 1 else 0 end=1
           AND (NextCall2 BETWEEN GETDATE() AND  DATEADD(hh, 1, GETDATE())))
      )
```

This is because the optimizer won't optimize the contents of fnPhoneExists.